# Is there a way to animate a camera along a curve at specific speed?

Tags: camera, bezier-curves

There are two ways to animate a camera along a path:
1) Follow path Constraint and 2) Parent (follow path) command

But they both have the same problem: The speed of the camera depends on the length of the curve. I want to have constant speed between different shots and scenes.

The way around is of course to calculate the length of the curve and determine the speed that way but it would be annoying and extra work since I have multiple separate shots.

Best regards, Eetu L

Comment: What specific speed?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you can do it with the standard tools, but I figured out a way using animation nodes that seems to work (someone might need to check my math). I basically created a subprogram that takes a Spline input and an object input(what will move along the spline). Then using some math, it takes the spline length, number of frames in the scene and a speed number and moves all the objects along their respective curves at that speed.

Maybe this will help you out, here's an example file.

[image]

[image]

edit: Thinking through this, you can probably replace the end frame value with just a float number set to some high number. That way this would keep the speed the same regardless of how long the scene is.

Comment: Seems very practical! I have only one newbie problem: Why the 3d-view is not updating continuously? I see the movement only when I execute Node tree manually. I have Auto Execution set to always.

Comment: Do you have the animation playing? Mine works when I scrub the playhead, don't need to click "Execute Node Tree". Are you on the latest build of Animation Nodes (I'm on version 2.1.5, and blender version 2.82 built on 2020-02-04)?

Comment: You were right. With the newest setup it works! I was using the latest official 2.8 build and Animation Nodes 2.1. Thanks for the solution and support!

Comment: I came a cross the new problem about smoothness of animation. The question can be found from here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167586

Answer (score 0):

You could try adjusting the origin point of the camera such that it will curve at the point you want it to. Note: This only works if the camera doesn't need to be moved along another curve-path.

Comment: mmm... I think I didn´t get you. How the origin point of the camera effects the speed?