# Animation nodes´ path animated camera is not smooth

Tags: bezier-curves, animation-nodes

I got an animation node script from this question ([Is there a way to animate a camera along a curve at specific speed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165906/is-there-a-way-to-animate-a-camera-along-a-curve-at-specific-speed)) and the node tree looks like this:

[image]

The setup works well (thanks for Crazycourier), but the problem is now that the movement is not 100% smooth.

The lagging can be seen at the final seconds of the video. It appears as small vibration when the camera looks towards the floor. The lagging might be hard to see from gif so here is the blend-file: 
[image]

What might cause this odd behavior?

[image]
I have tried to set curves resolution to maximum and to bake animation to key frames, but those have not helped.

Comment: Try changing the curve type from *Bezier* to *Path*

Comment: Conversion seems not to be possible because "Set Spline Type to poly" command lost all the smoothing from the curve. And drawing the exactly same curve again with the path is hard. Is there any other way? Disclaimer: I did not test does the path even work any better

Comment: "*I did not test does the path even work any better?*" Theoretically yes, in practice I don't know if that is the issue. You should be able to convert between any spline type arbitrarily regardless of poly. You may loose some of the original data, but you can change handles back to smooth again.

Comment: Mmm... Animation nodes can use only beziers as a splines so other formats don´t work. And conversion creates anyway different kind of path so that is not the solution. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: I think it is something to do with the fact how Animation nodes updates animations and creates keyframes

Comment: @DanielCookie The "Get Spline Length" node does not have enough resolution. So, select the node, open the properties panel (N-panel) then under "Advanced Node Settings" change the "Resolution = 64 or 128".

Comment: I feels that higher resolution makes vibration sometimes smoother, but it is clearly still there. Weird. Is there any other extra settings that I should check?